# why cursor not go to next line? When getline() take "\n" as an input

Tags: c++

I was learning from https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/an-introduction-to-stdstring/
and a question arises from the below code

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Pick 1 or 2: ";
    int choice{};
    std::cin >> choice;

    std::cout << "Now enter your name: ";
    std::string name{};
    std::getline(std::cin, name); // note: no std::ws here

    std::cout << "Hello, " << name << ", you picked " << choice << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

the question arising line is

```
std::getline(std::cin, name); // note: no std::ws here
```

here above code accepts '\n' as input for std::cin ok!

And the output is below

```
Pick 1 or 2: 2
Now enter your name: Hello, , you picked 2
```

Simple!

so my question is why the output does not go in the next line after 'Hello,' because std::cin takes the value "\n"?

the problem is not to buffer! I want to say that the output must print

```
Pick 1 or 2: 2
Now enter your name: Hello, 
, you picked 2
```

Comment: `std::cin >> choice;` does **not** consume the newline on the input stream.  To clear that newline, one fairly typical way is `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');`.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) for std::getline():

```
 getline reads characters from an input stream and places them into a string:
 1) Behaves as UnformattedInputFunction, except that input.gcount() is not affected. After constructing and checking the sentry object, performs the following:
    1) Calls str.erase()
    2) Extracts characters from input and appends them to str until one of the following occurs (checked in the order listed)
       a) end-of-file condition on input, in which case, getline sets eofbit.
       b) the next available input character is delim, as tested by Traits::eq(c, delim), in which case the delimiter character is extracted from input, but is not appended to str.
       c) str.max_size() characters have been stored, in which case getline sets failbit and returns.
```

Presumably you are running up against condition (b) above -- the newline character is recognized as a delimiter, "in which case the delimiter character is extracted from input, but is not appended to `str`"

(if you wanted to, you could do a `std::cout << name.size() << '\n';` to see how many characters are in your `name` string... I suspect you will see that there are zero, since when you just press enter, there are zero characters present before the newline/delimiter character)

Comment: But according to my question ```std::getline(std::cin, name);;``` here sts::cin gets input "\n" from buffer then output must be...  ```Pick 1 or 2: 2
Now enter your name: Hello, 
, you picked 2```  you can see my updated question in the last line.

Comment: You seem to be expecting that name will contain a newlune character, but std::getline() will never add a newline character to a string.

Answer (score 0):

because there is still a \n in the input buffer from the first read of `choice`, you need to tell cin to ignore it.

```
int choice{};
std::cin >> choice;
std::cin.ignore(); <<<=============
std::cout << "Now enter your name: ";
std::string name{};
```

EDIT

you wonder why name isnt equal to "\n" instead of ""

the reason is that getline ignores \n. it returns everything upto \n but not including the \n. So when the input buffer just has \n in it getline returns an empty string into `name`

Comment: Read my full question at the last line.

Comment: @kNIG132103 i did read it and the english is not clear. My change makes your program behave correctly, plus I explained why it didnt work. What more do you need?

Comment: sorry for the bad English. My question is if the buffer givers the input to the next cin then why the program gives the output only an empty string! the cursor must go to the next line. and thanks for your answer.

Comment: @kNIG132103 its fine, but if you still have a question please edit the question above and be clearer. But do it once you have understood why my fix worked

Comment: I edited my question. And now you can see what I want.

Comment: @kNIG132103 I update my answer